# Circuit solving problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

I am a high school boy and came across this question: 
[image: Circuit]

I have solved this question by KVL, but how do I solve this question by potential distribution method?

What I have tried :)

I assume two type of current, \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$, by two different voltage sources. So 50 volt battery has the current \$i_1\$. Both branches are of 4 ohm so current distribute in early ratio, and same thing I apply with 20 volt battery. I do not how to approach the solution, is this analysis correct?

Comment: A [very similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/512050/find-current-and-power-in-a-circuit) was asked in Physics. Have you seen the answers over there?

Comment: Also, just like on the Physics SE, for this kind of question you should show what you've already tried and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: Yes  I have seen, but I want how do I solve it by potential distribution method.

Comment: OK , let me show what I have tried.

Comment: @yuvrajsingh Never heard of "potential distribution methods" outside of thermodynamics, where there exists a potential distribution theorem. Can you translate the method name differently for us? (There is the use of KVL. But separately, the use of KCL. Sometimes the term "mesh analysis" is used along with "nodal analysis." Can you help us understand better?)

Comment: It mean we can assume a certain point a reference potential zero, and calculate the in the branches according to it.

Comment: In the case above I would split the circuit, make two Thevenin equivalents, then re-combine. I find that easier then solving 3 equations with 3 unknowns.

Comment: Sure if you have answer please post it by your method.

Comment: I do not post answers to school assignments following the general site consensus on this subject: "In general, homework questions enjoy/suffer a special treatment.
We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic
questions and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your
own, which you have not I am afraid. Otherwise, we would be doing you a
disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time.
See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036)"

Comment: That correct, neither I am asking the whole answer, I am just asking how do I approach it others than kvl.

Comment: I have shown, my efforts, if you can go through my mistake it will be more good.

Comment: @Oldfart There are only 2 unknowns - the 4R resistors are in parallel.

Comment: `It mean we can assume a certain point a reference potential zero` If you did this using KVL, surely you assumed one node as reference or ground or zero. So whats the point of this question ?

Comment: @Chu OOOps I missed that! I must be getting old and senile.

Comment: @Oldfart I'm in that club too!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by potential distribution you mean the nodal analysis method.

We select some node as our ground (zero potential). This is completely arbitrary, it's usually good to take sth next to a voltage source, so I'll pick the bottom left corner. Next we observe that the two 4 Ohm resistors are in parallel, so we can simplify that branch to a single 2 Ohm resistor. I will designate the current flowing through that component as [image: I_3] and it's direction from the top of the circuit into our ground node. I will also designate the currents [image: I_1] and [image: I_3] the way you did, but specify that they flow "up" on this schematic.

For voltages, let the voltage of the node in the top right corner be [image: V_A] and [image: V_B] for the node in the bottom right corner.

Now you can write voltage relationships created by voltage sources, the top left corner is at 50V, due to a source between it and ground. The 20V voltage source between [image: V_A] and [image: V_B] impleies that:

$$V_A + 20V = V_B$$

Then you can use Ohm's Law to write down voltage-current relationships for all loads:

$$0V - V_B = 2I_2$$
$$V_A - 0V = 2I_3$$
$$50V - V_A = 2I_1$$

Finally, using KCL on either of the T-junctions we get a 5th relationship exclusively between currents:

$$I_1 + I_2 = I_3$$

Solving this will give you the answer.

Note that the choice of ground and the direction of currents is arbitrary, it will eventually lead to the same answer as long as you are consistent with your calculations. I encourage you to do this again, but select a different node as your ground and see if your new answer is coherent with this one. The relative voltages should be shifted by some constant up or down, while the currents should remain the same.